# Getting better resolution in console mode (nVidia drivers)

Tags: command-line, nvidia, display, display-resolution

Some time ago, while trying to update my desktop system from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, something failed, and I ended with a non working graphical environment.

This forced me to use the console (Ctrl+Alt+F3), which was working well. Actually, it was working very well. The screen was fully used, fonts were crisp, and even though they were small, just by virtue of fitting perfectly with the monitor's resolution, they were highly readable. I ended having a very large working space. In association with `tmux`, it was a perfect development environment.

I felt so well in this new setup that I neglected repairing the graphical environment for a few weeks. However, one thing dearly missing from text mode is Firefox, and there is only so much I could do without ever accessing it. So I fixed the issue, which was apparently related to the nVidia graphics drivers. Just uninstalling and reinstalling fixed it. And now the graphical environment works perfectly.

So, I don't exactly "need" the console mode anymore, but since I liked it, I wanted to use it again, and to my dismay, resolution was set to a default 1024x768. The crips fonts were gone, text is now oversized and blurry, reducing work environment, and featuring a disagreeable read experience.

So, I went up to search some solution. And it happens that this question is asked quite often. I found many variants of the same answer, and all of them point to `grub`.

Now, this is strange, because in the above scenario, console resolution was changed while `grub` wasn't modified the slightest. So it smells fishy. I nonetheless reluctantly tried it. A good variant of the `grub` solution can be [read here](https://oette.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/how-to-change-console-fontsize-and-resolution-on-ubuntu-server/). So I applied it, using my monitor's resolution, but it did not worked. The resolution is still low and blurry.

Digging deeper, I find some advises on how to select a video mode starting with listing them using `vbeinfo` on `grub`. It doesn't work. Later I see a note to use `videoinfo` instead. This one works, but only lists "low resolution" modes, from 640 to 1280, in 4x3 format.

Finally, [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258490/46330) suggests to use `hwinfo`, which is available in user mode. This one lists more modes, but still not the one of my monitor.

```
sudo hwinfo --framebuffer 
02: None 00.0: 11001 VESA Framebuffer                           
  [Created at bios.459]
  Unique ID: xxxx
  Hardware Class: framebuffer
  Model: "NVIDIA GPU Board"
  Vendor: "NVIDIA Corporation"
  Device: "GPU Board"
  SubVendor: "NVIDIA"
  SubDevice: 
  Revision: "Chip Rev"
  Memory Size: 16 MB
  Memory Range: 0x01000000-0x01ffffff (rw)
  Mode 0x0301: 640x480 (+640), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0303: 800x600 (+1024), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0305: 1024x768 (+1024), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0307: 1280x1024 (+1280), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0311: 640x480 (+1280), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0312: 640x480 (+2560), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0314: 800x600 (+2048), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0315: 800x600 (+4096), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0317: 1024x768 (+2048), 16 bits
  Mode 0x0318: 1024x768 (+4096), 24 bits
  Mode 0x031a: 1280x1024 (+2560), 16 bits
  Mode 0x031b: 1280x1024 (+5120), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0345: 1600x1200 (+1664), 8 bits
  Mode 0x0346: 1600x1200 (+3328), 16 bits
  Mode 0x034a: 1600x1200 (+6656), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0371: 1360x768 (+6144), 24 bits
  Mode 0x0377: 1920x1080 (+7680), 24 bits
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
```

My monitor offers a native resolution of 1680x1050, a 16:10 format.
It's not present in this list.
This seems to suggest that the graphics card is not able to handle.

Yet, it works perfectly fine in graphical mode. And what's even more strange is that Console Mode at 1680x1050 used to work perfectly while the graphic driver were in bad shape. Somehow, fixing the graphic driver made the situation worse for console mode.

Is there anything that can be attempted on top of the previously described actions ?

*edit* : I tried my luck with `rEFInd`, which offers a more sensible configuration experience through `refind.conf`. I guess it also means the `grub2` trick is no longer valid.
Anyway, setting `resolution 1680 1050` doesn't work, and boot immediately complains about it, restricting the choice to `640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024`.
So I guess `rEFInd` is constrained to select one among them, likely due to limits in what nVidia VGA Bios supports.

However, it feels strange to me that the console would be constrained to just "inherit" the same resolution as the boot loader. And it still doesn't explain why a console at 1680x1050 was working fine before fixing the graphics driver.

*edit 2* : modifying the resolution of `grub` to `1280x1024`, which is one of the resolutions allowed by `videoinfo`, is successful in modifying the resolution of Ubuntu tty to the same `1280x1024`. At last, some impact. It increases workspace from the default `1024x768`, but fonts are even less readable ...
Still no explanation as to why tty using `1680x1050` was working fine while nvidia drivers were in shamble.

*edit 3* : I now suspect that, while my graphic environment was not working, the graphic driver was probably provided by `nouveau`. It was unfortunately incompatible with my graphic card because it was too new (it's an RTX2080). But somehow, `nouveau` has a working framebuffer implementation which makes it possible to have high-res console, something that is strangely missing from the official nVidia drivers ...

*edit 4* : As requested by @Naoyuki Tai, but run over an SSH remote session :

```
sudo fbset -i

mode "1024x768-76"
    # D: 78.653 MHz, H: 59.949 kHz, V: 75.694 Hz
    geometry 1024 768 1024 768 32
    timings 12714 128 32 16 4 128 4
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : EFI VGA
    Address     : 0x53000000
    Size        : 3145728
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 0
    YPanStep    : 0
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 4096
    Accelerator : No
```

Comment: nVidia frame buffer implementation is pretty good compared to ATI. Probably using VESA driver of xorg is sufficient for not so fast use. AFAIR, nouveau driver supports limited chipsets and I don’t know what it supports now. Info should be on xorg web site driver section. nVidia native driver works well tho. Check out nVidia web site for native driver?

Comment: I'm currently using nVidia (closed source) drivers.
I've been reading a lot about this topic, and it seems accepted that nVidia framebuffer implementation is just plain missing, or if it is present, is not accessible to console mode. In contrast, `nouveau` driver do that part just right.

Unfortunately, 3D performance of `nouveau` driver is sluggish, thanks in no small part to lack of information from nVidia, making it an imperfect replacement.

As a consequence, I've stopped using the console mode.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you running X11? If not, "native driver" is not involved. It's for Xorg server to drive the screen, including 3d. Console uses VESA mode frame buffer. When X server is running, it takes a tty? and not use the frame buffer. Instead, it uses the graphics card's. If you switch to other tty, then, you are seeing the VESA frame buffer. I thought you were using the "console" - the VESA frame buffer. Are you talking about a terminal emulation running on X server?

Comment: It's really about the "console", like <Ctrl+Alt+F3>, so I guess it's using the (VESA ?) frame buffer. 
But what is not clear to me is what is the role of `nouveau` and the nVidia video driver in this story. I always thought that VESA go straight to the video bios, without any intervention from the driver. 
But that's not consistent with my observations : I had a crispy clear console experience when the nVidia driver was off (I assume OS used `nouveau` instead), with a 1650x1080 resolution, while available VESA modes of my graphic card seem limited to 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768 and 1280x1024.

Comment: nouveau/native nVidia driver are only used by X server. So, if you are using console, you are using VESA frame buffer. I think I am getting warmer. You did run X server, and once do you, the VESA frame buffer setting changed. And you want to "keep" the original VESA mode that the driver is indeed involved running X.

Comment: The nVidia chip is probably capable of running both VESA emulation and full graphics, and your question is "how to set the VESA mode back to the original that is set by the boot process". If the chip is capable, it should respond to setting the frame buffer resolution. Try:

"fbset /dev/fb0 -g 1600 1050 1600 1050 8"

Also, do "fbset -i" and see what comes out. This should tell you the current FB geometry. I'm not 100% sure of the correct value for the resolution part so you may have to try some variations. See man fbset.

Comment: Thanks , I will try the `fbset` suggestion.
Note though that I _do __not__ want_ the VESA mode set by the boot process. I want the native resolution of my screen, which is 1680x1050. The boot process actually uses 1024x768, which is the resolution I'm also currently getting when using `console`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the result from `fbset -i`. Formatting is much better in the question.

Comment: I see. I think the booting process does a lot of voodoo for frame buffer, and one of things it does is to figure out the max resolution of your monitor and adjust the frame buffer using fbset. I do not know where it happens but I'm pretty sure that it is getting the "fbset -i" as well as the EDID of your monitor and setting max possible again using "fbset". The voodoo part is how the command is getting EDID from console, and figuring out the max possible resolution. Smarts is in the booter's script which I have no clue where it is happening but you can tell it happens near the end of booting.